# CGAL - Polyhedron dijkstra shortest path

Tags: cgal

I found that for BGL computations on

```
CGAL::Polyhedron_3<K,CGAL::Polyhedron_items_with_id_3>
```

the squared distance is used for edge weigths, which is defined in:
CGAL/boost/graph/properties_Polyhedron_3.h

This produces wrong results on polyhedral meshes.

How can I change the weight metric without changing CGAL code?

My work around is that I change

```
reference operator[](key_type const& e) const
  {
    return CGAL::squared_distance(e->vertex()->point(), e->opposite()->vertex()->point());
  }
```

in class Polyhedron_edge_weight_map to

```
reference operator[](key_type const& e) const
  {
    return sqrt(CGAL::squared_distance(e->vertex()->point(), e->opposite()->vertex()->point()));
  }
```

Any ideas?

thanks and the best,
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Note that the weightmap is a parameter of the function [dijksta_shortest_path](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html)

Comment: Do you know how to assign weights to an weightmap of a polyhedron? I've tried it with get(boost::edge_weight, polyhedron) but I can only read the values and not write them.